# Scanning folders (os walk), add updated files and folders to sqlite3

Tags: python, sqlite, treeview

Background: I have a sqlite database which contains the result of the below code with lots of information on files in a given treestructure I need to keep some kind of track on. Occationally I'm adding files and folders to the given location.

Goal: Now, I want to make this code run, so that it adds files to the given database, but only if it does not already exist. How can I make this work without the risk of deleting data I manually added to the Information columns?

The parent column is made so I can represent it as a filetree with Tkinter Treeview.

```
from os import walk
import sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('Win10.db')
print("Opened database successfully")
conn.execute('''DROP TABLE IF EXISTS Windows10''')
conn.execute('''CREATE  TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Windows10 
        ("Node"             INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "Filename"          TEXT,
        "Path"              TEXT    NOT NULL,
        "Beginner Info"     TEXT    DEFAULT 'Info',
        "Intermediate Info" TEXT    DEFAULT 'Info',
        "Advanced Info"     TEXT    DEFAULT 'Info',
        "Tags"              TEXT    DEFAULT 'separated by whitespace tags',
        "Parent"            INTEGER NOT NULL,
        "isFolder"          INTEGER DEFAULT NULL,
        "fileExt"           TEXT DEFAULT NULL,
        PRIMARY             KEY("Node")
    )''')
print("Table created successfully")

folder_list = {}
node = 1
fileExt = ""
my_path = "C:\\"
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in walk(my_path):
    # Always starts by opening/viewing a folder
    isFolder = 1

    # Current file name is the last name in the path. Stripped for backslashes, but getting one back at the end
    curr_filename = dirpath.split("\\")[-1] + "\\"

    parent_node = 1

    # A folders parent folder
    parent_folder_of_folder = dirpath.split("\\")
    # Adding back the stripped backslash to make its name more visible as a folder
    pfof_name = ""
    for i in parent_folder_of_folder[:-1]:
        pfof_name += i + "\\"

    # Adds only dirpath if it does not exist, and because folderlist is hardcoded at first index, we'll skip it.
    if dirpath not in folder_list:
        match = {node: dirpath}
        folder_list[str(node)] = dirpath

    for key, value in folder_list.items():
        # Makes parent node set to its belonging index and checks if it is a folder to avoid a folder to be set as
        # its own parent.
        if dirpath == value and isFolder == 0:
            parent_node = key
            break
        # Sets parent_node to the key of its parent folder by checking that it is a folder and what the splitted
        # output of its path up to its folder name is equal to.
        elif (pfof_name.rstrip("\\")) == value and isFolder == 1:
            parent_node = key
            break
    # Parameters to execute for folders
    params = (curr_filename, dirpath, parent_node, fileExt, isFolder)
    conn.execute('''INSERT INTO Windows10 (Filename,Path,Parent,fileExt,isFolder)
                 VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', params)
    # Iterate over every file inside a folder
    for i in filenames:
        # Starting file iteration - turn isFolder to False.
        isFolder = 0
        curr_filename = i

        # Iterate over our folder list to check for a match of current file's parent folder. Break when found.
        for key, value in folder_list.items():
            if dirpath == value:
                parent_node = key
                print(key, value)
                break

        # If current file is not a folder and contains a "dot" which may indicate to be an extension, save its ext.
        # Works only for explicit files thus far. Not reading file-headers at all.
        if isFolder == 0 and "." in curr_filename.split("\\")[-1]:
            fileExt = curr_filename.split(".")[-1]

        # Parameters to execute in sqlite for files
        params = (curr_filename, dirpath + "\\" + curr_filename, parent_node, fileExt, isFolder)
        conn.execute('''INSERT INTO Windows10 (Filename,Path,Parent,fileExt,isFolder)
                     VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)''', params)
        # Node iteration to keep up with
        node += 1
        # File iteration done, next up is folder, unless more iterations
        isFolder = 1
        # Make file extension to NULL
        fileExt = ""
    node += 1
conn.commit()
print("Records created successfully")
conn.close()
```

Known bugs:
It works fine as far as I've tested, except for one thing I can't seem to figure out. When running on smaller folders with not too many files it works, but if I run it on my whole C drive the parent column is missing out on something. It makes every folder inside the C drive (not recursively through those) to appear with parent node 0, although it should be of parent node 1 which would be the C folder/drive. This makes me think that it does not recognize those as inside the C drive.

I have tried to figure this one out on my own, but I've been bashing my head for too long now. I'm hoping for a simple solution that will make me grow as a programmer!

Any suggestion for improvement would also be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try building a dictionary?

```
from __future__ import print_function

import os
from json import dumps as json_dumps

searchpath = '.'
data = {}
for prefix, dirs, files in os.walk(searchpath):
    absprefix = os.path.abspath(prefix)
    for filename in files:
        relpath = os.path.join(prefix, filename)
        abspath = os.path.abspath(relpath)
        parentdir = os.path.basename(absprefix)
        stem, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
        isdir = os.path.isdir(abspath)
        isfile = os.path.isfile(abspath)
        islink = os.path.islink(abspath)
        ismount = os.path.ismount(abspath)
        data[abspath] = {'filename': filename, 'absprefix': absprefix, 'prefix': prefix, 'searchpath': searchpath, 'relpath': relpath, 'parentdir': parentdir, 'stem': stem, 'ext': ext, 'isdir': isdir, 'isfile': isfile, 'islink': islink, 'ismount': ismount}

print(json_dumps(data, indent=4))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).